# how to prevent propagation of the same event in different components in angular with HostListener?

Tags: javascript, angular, events

I have two components, and they both are listening to keyboard inputs. If in one of them a certain condition is met, then I want to prevent any other action happening after listening to those events. Here's a snippet:

component 1 (an full screen overlay):

```
@HostListener("document:keydown", ["$event"])
public handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    if (!this.isShow) {
        return;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.returnValue = false;
}
```

component 2 (a dialog):

```
@HostListener("document:keydown.escape", ["$event"]) 
public onEscKeyUp(e: KeyboardEvent): void {
    this.dial.close();
}
```

So when the overlay is showing , i don't want the dialog to close, if that makes sense. I have that code, but it does not work.

Comment: One is `keydown.escape` and other one is if any keyPressed on the keyboard specially when the key is going down. What does this mean "So when the first one is showing, i don't want the second one to close" what are you trying to show or hide?

Comment: thank you, i have edited my question to make it more clear. One component is an overlay, the other component is a dialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured out how to make it work:

```
@HostListener("document:keydown", ["$event"])
public handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent): boolean
{
    if (!this.isShow)
    {
        return true;
    }
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So your second component is fine, it will only be called when the user call the `escape` event from the keyboard. There is a problem in the first component and when the user presses any key including `escape`, it will be called.

You can add a condition for `escape` :

```
@HostListener("document:keydown", ["$event"])
public handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    if (!this.isShow) {
        return;
    }
     // keycode for escape
    if (event.keyCode === 27) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        return;
    }

    // as per @solar's answer
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    //event.returnValue = false; // why do you need this
    return false;
}
```

Comment: hi, thank you but this is not really helping, as I want to stop the event from propagating, therefore not reaching the modal component. I want it to stop at the overlay. but the code I added after (like event.stopPropagation();) doesnt seem to work and I don't know why

Comment: that doesn't work.. it is not really different from what i had before and I guess event.stoppropagation probably doesn't work as i thought it did with HostListener

Comment: If you can update the code on stackblitz, i can take a look at it. There might be some binding issues.

Comment: thank you. to put the whole code there would be a lot of work atm. But basically these two components are not immediate siblings, but far away from each other, if that makes a difference.

Comment: You have different event which are being called in both the component, I am unable to understand what causes the issue if you keydown event should be captured in component one rather than in component 2 (as it it for escape only).